# Image link few pixels off on every browser except Opera

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have an issue with [the site](http://jsfiddle.net/Jxrw7/2) I am working on.

The top logo seems to have some kind of margin to the top, even though I have specifically set it to have no margin and its parents' have no padding.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    min-width: 320px;

    background-image: url('../images/templates/background.png');

    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #303030;
}
```

Here's an image with different browsers I tested:

[image: odd margins]

As you can see, only Opera seems to work properly. Now is there anything wrong in it? Or is it an issue of browsers?

If this is an issue with browsers, what would be the easiest way to solve the issue?

Comment: It would have been better if you gave a jsfiddle of the problem rather than just a link to your website

Comment: Made a quick jsfiddle for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxrw7/2/

Comment: Here is my update to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxrw7/4/ you need to tell your image to `display:block` it gets rid of all the hidden padding that browsers add to images

Comment: Please edit your post to actually include code. Do not circumvent the system by formatting fake code, i.e., `Thanks in advance.`

Comment: I didn't do that on purpose, also why come comment here on this over 2 year old question? I changed the question just for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's line 98 in main.css thats causing your issue.

```
.menuAvatar {
vertical-align: middle; // THIS LINE
margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

When vertical align is removed the image aligns correctly.  You can either find a different way to accomplish what you are using the `vertical-align` for, or you can use the following ways to compensate.

```
.menuAvatar {
vertical-align: middle;
margin: -3px 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

I added -3px to margin-top to force it to align back in Chrome.  (not tested in firefox and others).

OR use this to avoid negative margins.

```
.menuAvatar {
vertical-align: top; 
margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 98 of `main.css`, you have the following rule:

```
.menuAvatar{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;;
}
```

I would recommend setting `vertical-align` to `top`, resulting in:

```
.menuAvatar{
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```